# Prove that, there infinitely many terms have exactly $m$ distinct prime factors

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-progressions

> Let $X_n$ be an infinite arithmetic sequence with positive integers term. The first term is divisible by the common difference of successive members. Suppose, the term $x_i$ has  exactly $m>1$ distinct prime factors, for some $i\in\Bbb N$.
>
> **Prove that, there infinitely many terms have exactly $m$ distinct prime factors.**

My some thoughts.

Let $x_1$ has $n$ distinct prime factors and $x_2=x_1+d$ where $d\mid x_1\implies x_1=dk$. Hence $x_2=x_1+d=d(1+k)$. But, we can not say anything about the prime factors of $x_2$. Therefore, we don't know the number of prime factors of $x_2$. By induction we don't know the number of prime factors of $x_3$.

I tried to make the solution by induction, but as it seems I could not be successful.

Comment: It seems like if $d$ has more than $n$ distinct prime factors, then so will $x_k$ for all $k$; isn't there a counterexample based on that?  (Edit: never mind, the fact that $x_i$ has exactly $n$ distinct prime factors for some $i$ means this can't happen.  And in fact it tells you something important about $d$.  Can you make progress from there?)

Comment: $x_{n + 1} = d \cdot (k + n)$. Depending on $n$, what is minimum and maximum number of prime factors this number can potentially have?

Comment: Also, this claim is not exactly true: if $x_1 = d = 1$, then $x_1$ has exactly zero prime factors, but all other terms have more.

Comment: @mihaild see the question's statement please. You misunderstood the question

Comment: @Mathlove what exactly? Which part of the statement the setup "$X_n = n$, $i = 1$, $m = 0$" doesn't satisfy?

Comment: @mihaild please define "zero distinct" primes. This doesn't make sense. $m>1$ is obvious.

Comment: So say $x_i = \prod p_i=N$ with $n$ prime factors.  Then $x_{i+k} =N + kd$.  Now if $k$ is a multiple $N$ then all the prime factors of $N$ we be factors of $x_{i+k}$.  But then we'd also have a factor of $1+\frac kn d$.  But here we go:  Suppose we let $N' =\frac N{p_m}$ so $N'$ has exactly $n-1$ prime factors. Then if $j$ is a multiple of $N'$ then $x_{i+j}$ will have all the factors of $N'$ (excpept $p_m$) and all the factors of $1+\frac j{N'}d$.  We just need to prove that $1+\frac j{N'}d$ can be prime an infinite number of times. I.E for $d$ there are infinitely many prime $1+wd$s.

Comment: @Mathlove it is not obvious, and should be stated in question. How many distinct prime factors does number $1$ have in your opinion? "Zero distinct primes" means exactly that: the set of prime factors of $1$ is empty (has zero elements).

Comment: @mihaild is right, $1$ has zero prime factors (i.e., the set of primes that divide $1$ is the empty set, which has cardinality zero), and the sequence $1,2,3,\ldots$ doesn't contain infinitely many terms like that.  So the problem statement should just say $n>0$ or that the terms are greater than $1$.

Comment: It's not worth arguing but I think @mihalid is exactly right.  "zero distinct" primes is clearly and unambiguously just that and the unitary $1$ is the only natural number satisfying that.  That is well known and universally agreed upon. So $x_1=1; d=1$ and $\{x_i\} = \mathbb N$ and $i=1$ is an obvious but trivial exception.  This is probably true for all other cases. (Um... what is $m$?)

Comment: "You can not define zero different apple. It is just meaningless. "  Huh?  "Zero different apples" makes perfect sense.  It means you don't have any apples.

Comment: @fleablood I fixed. Actually the original question states $m>1$. I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the AP is $a_{n+1} = d\cdot(k+n)$ for some $k,d \in \mathbb{N}$. Let
$x_1 = d(k+r)$ for some $ r \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $x_t = d(k + ((k+r)^t - k))$ for any $t \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $x_t$ has the exact same prime factors as $x_1$. To show that this an infinite sequence, we only need to show that the terms are all distinct which is equivalent to $k + r = 1$. But as $k, r \ge 1$ we have $k + r \ge 2$, qed.

Answer (score 0):

We can be blunt.

Just prove there are are an infinite number of terms with the exact same prime factors (and thus the same number of factors)

All terms or multiples of $d$ and *all* multiples of $d$ that are equal to or greater than $x_1$ are terms.  So if $x_i$ is a multiple of $d$ that is $\ge x_1$ with a unique factorization of $\prod p_i^{a_i}$ then any $\prod p_i^{b_i}; b_i \ge a_i$ will be a multiple of $d$ that is $\ge x_1$ so is also a term of the sequence.

And clearly there are an infinite number of them.

=====

To put it in the terms you started:

Let $x_{w} = d(k+w-1)$.  Then $x_{w+(k+w-1)^j-(k+w-1)} = d(k+w-1)^j$ will have the exact same prime factors as $x_w$.  And there are an infinite number of $j$s.  The end.

====

Note these are way overkill.  But if overkill makes things easier than so be it.  "Welcome to New York City!  Our population is larger than 17!"